# iOS 8 - performSegueWithIdentifier loads view but doesn't show until I tap the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a Tab Bar application, and one of the tabs, which contains a Table View, segues into a third view when a table cell is pressed. The view controller acts as a delegate for the UITableView, and I trigger the segue programatically as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("cell tapped, starting segue")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("prep for segue")
    // TODO - more code here
}
```

Finally, I set up the following code to debug the problem with the third view:

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("did load")
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        println("will appear")
    }
}
```

The **problem is** that when I press a table cell for the first time, the `viewWillAppear` function never gets called until I interact with the UI in some way (e.g. just a tap anywhere on the screen). The view that I want to segue into doesn't show up, as if the screen didn't get refreshed. However, when I tap the screen, the whole animation runs and I can segue as intended. This is my output when I tap a cell:

```
cell tapped, starting segue
prep for segue
did load
```

I tried to find solutions online, but all the issues I found it seems to just not work at all. In my case, it is working, but not immediately.

In case it helps, here's a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: Screenshot of my Storyboard]

Comment: It doesn't look like much is in that next view controller... What is it? Just a label set in prepareForSegue or something? And if that's the case, could you post the code?

Comment: @LyndseyScott you mean the DetailsViewController? That's all the code I have there right now. I'm not actually passing any data through yet, just trying to get it animating first. The view itself is just a menu bar and a label I added from the storyboard editor.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought maybe you were performing some sort of action in the background, but I guess that's not the case... I'll think it over a bit...

Comment: And that's 100% of your code, right? Like you're not trying to perform any long tasks in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, that's literally a copy/paste of the whole file. In the initial View Controller, there is some more complex code to handle loading data into the table cells, but none of it gets called when the segue happens (I checked to make sure).

Comment: So I got the symptoms of the problem to go away by allowing the cells to be highlighted when tapped (before I set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None`). It's still bothering me that this problem is probably still somewhere in there, but at least it works now.

Comment: Hm... Strange... But glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sefu found the answer and posted it in the comments, I ran into the same issue and his solution worked for me.  The trick is to make it so the cell that is selected that triggers the segue needs to have a selection style set (not None), and I also found that deselecting the cell in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: also needed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem while having my selectionStyle = .None . 
An option you can use, if you're like me and don't want a selectionStyle applied is to set the cell item back to unselected in the prep for segue.
That seemed to stopped the 'issue' I was seeing where the segue would work perfectly once, but all subsequent calls would require selecting the cell twice.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //sending the index path up as the sender so the prep for segue can access the cell
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID", sender: indexPath);
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueID"){
        if let indexPath : NSIndexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath{
            tableViewReference.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.selected = false;

            let destinationVC : UIViewControllerClass = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewControllerClass;
            destinationVC.customMethod(/* some value */);

        }
    }
}
```